# O. Leroy's thesis on fundamental groupoids

Tags: ho.history-overview, topos-theory

Does someone have a copy of the [O. Leroy's thesis](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=54636):

*Groupoïde fondamental et théorème de van Kampen en théorie des topos*

or has the ability to make a digitalization ?  The thesis was done at Université Montpellier II 1978.

Comment: Just for information, Olivier Leroy died in 1996.

Comment: Here you can find a transcript https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/leroy.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Jean Malgoire kindly sent me a scan back to 2015, with authorization to transmit it. So here it is:

Link:

https://plmbox.math.cnrs.fr/f/7ffa366379144dd4bacc/

Direct Download Link:

https://plmbox.math.cnrs.fr/f/7ffa366379144dd4bacc/?dl=1

The password is : groupoide

Actually, the plan was to type it in $\LaTeX$ and send it to arXiv. As far as I know, this has not be done yet. That being said, if enough people are interested, we could make a collaborative project. Please just leave an answer if you are (especially if you already have some expertise in such projects !). Of course, this could be the opportunity to translate the text into english.

Comment: A GitHub repo with separate files for different sections that people can make pull requests on would be good. I would be interested, though my French is rudimentary.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Git was also what I had in mind. Something along the lines of https://github.com/thescrivener/PursuingStacks or https://github.com/stacks/stacks-project . French shouldn't be an issue, I am much more afraid of translating into correct English.

Comment: There's no shortage of people who can work on polishing the English. Mere transcribing of French to LaTeX is no problem at all.

Comment: I know someone else (in fact the OP, who contacted me privately) who would be interested in helping type this up.

Comment: He also got in touch with me. It seems that he decided to type the whole phd by himself : https://github.com/agrothendieck/agrothendieck.github.io/tree/master/galoispoincaregrothendieck/leroy . Very good news !

Comment: I think I still want to get an English version typed up.

Answer (score 2):

You can place an order here: https://catalogue.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb347650117. This shouldn't pose much of a problem if you are somewhat familiar with French.